# Действие при каждом сотом значении

Tags: php

```
$var = "99";
```

**$var** постоянно увеличивается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как ловить каждое сотое значение (100, 200, ..., 10200 и т.д) и выполнять условие

```
if (.....) {
  echo "true";
} else {
  echo "false";
}
```

Comment: поставить счетчик и обнулять его при значении 100.Или, использовать функцию округления. if ($var/100==round($var/100,0))

Comment: @DrMcSheen слишком нерационально. проще просто проверять остаток при делении на 100

Comment: Согласен с @DrMcSheen, необходимо проверять делится ли на 100 без остатка.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (substr($count, -2) == '00') {
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно преобразовать тип $var в integer `$var = (int)$var`. В условии написать

```
if($var%100 == 0 && $var > 0) ...
```